# Udfs shared context in Pig

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I've come across a problem figuring out what those lines below actually mean:

> When using the object in the exec method, keep in mind that any
>   changes made to the returned Properties will not be transmitted to
>   other instances of the UDF on the backend, unless you happen to have
>   another instance of the same UDF in the same task

Those are lines from the book programming pig(page 131), and for putting you in context all of this have to do with UDFs in Pig, and the execution context, which all instances of the same UDF can share context from the frontend(Compilation) to the backend(Running).

The think I don't understand at all is, what is the meaning of this line

```
...you happen to have another instance of the same UDF in the same task
```

What I take away out of that is that has some bearing on **speculative execution**, that is the speculative task is actually sharing the same instance of the UDF with the normal task being launched previously(in the Pig context), or otherwise I totally have a misconception of the way I understand all of this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking a guess here, so I wouldn't mind some validation from someone else.

I imagine you could have the same instance of the same UDF in the same task if you are calling the UDF multiple times. I don't think they are talking about speculative execution. E.g.:

```
B = FOREACH A GENERATE udf1(col1), udf1(col2), udf1(col3);
```

I imagine what this is trying to explain is that you can't change state/context in the UDF and expect it to propagated to others. The class is being instantiated several times, once for each task in general.